# insert underscore in columns of a text file shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a tab separated text file f.txt like  :

APPLE   10   5

BALL    20   6

CAT     30   7

I want the output to be

APPLE_10_5

BALL_20_6

CAT_30_7

I wrote the following to partially accomplish this, but I am stuck at the "paste" step. Can you help?

```
cat f.txt | cut -f 1,2,3 | paste ???
```

Comment: Just replace all " " (Space chars) with "_" underscore, using sed.

Comment: What did you expect the cut to do?

Comment: @cb0 That would be a useless use of `sed`. `tr` is the tool you want to use here.

Comment: Thanks, what makes `tr` more powerfull for this than `sed`. Could you please explain in some words or give a link.

Answer (score 0):

When the are sperated by one space using sed is a one liner.

```
sed -i "s/ /_/" input.txt
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this answer: (a) it just replaces the first instance of a space per line (b) it will work with GNU sed only, because of the usage of `-i` without a backup extension (c) useless use of `sed` since `tr` should be used (d) no need to answer a closed question which has been answered already.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! I tried but was missing point (b) because of only one whitespace. Btw. I answer before it was closed :)